# Logic operators in return statement in C

Tags: c, coding-style, return, logic

I have recently been learning C, and have come across a few return statements with logical operators in them, ie

```
return(statement LOGIC statement);
```

Where the statements evaluate to True or false (ie 1 or 0), and LOGIC is a logical operator like &&, || etc.

Is this good coding practice, as it seems a bit off to me, would it not be better to use if/else if statements?

Comment: That looks to me like saying using `&&` in an if-clause is bad practice or using the ternary operator is evil. Depends on readability, personal preference, etc.

Comment: Define *good coding practice*

Comment: One could argue having only *one* exit point to function is even "better" coding style.

Comment: You don't need `else` if the first condition executes a `return`.

Comment: Return is not a function, don't treat return(); as a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this coding practice and actually you don't need the parentheses. Beware of lazy evaluation.

`return foo1() && foo2()`

If the return value of the call to `foo1` is false `foo2` never gets called.

Comment: I think that the correct term is `short-circuiting`

Comment: `short-circuiting` is more common apparently but I defend `lazy evaluation` as equally correct in this case. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) says "Short-circuit evaluation of Boolean control structures is sometimes called lazy".

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather do

```
return a && b;
```

or

```
int result = a && b;
return result;
```

just because there's less opportunity to screw up.  If you write

```
if ( a && b )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

you always run the risk of getting the sense of the test wrong (i.e., returning `false` when you meant to return `true` and vice-versa).  It's not a *significant* risk, but it's there.

Back before C99 introduced built-in symbolic constants for `true` and `false`, people typically defined their own `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros.  Problem is, some of those people would occasionally mis-spell `0` and `1`.  I once spent an afternoon chasing my tail because someone dropped a header where `TRUE` and `FALSE` expanded to the *same value*.

Not coincidentally, that's when I started using `return expr` instead of `return TRUE` or `return FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

Omitting the if is good coding style. Using `if cond return true else return false` is overly long and redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the programmer. Few feel comfortable to use a logical operator and either return a 0 or 1, while others may feel that a bit off.

Practically speaking, both doesn't have any difference at all in the way it works; and also I don't exactly think it's a bad programming practice.

But yes, `if` and `else` may have more readability and hence helps readers.

Answer (score 0):

It is your preference that matters. But, looking at complex solutions and implementing them often helps you understand intricate details on C. A simple demonstration being :

```
 char mystring[10];
 //assume you take the input
 //to print it:
 int i;
 for(i=0;mystring[i]!='\0';i++)
 printf("%c",mystring[i]);
```

The above can be re-written in a complex way:

```
char *ch;
for(ch=mystring; *ch; ch++)
printf("%c",*ch);
```

This beautifully shows the intricate details of how pointers get evaluated. And understanding this and using this definitely shows and helps you understand C better.

So, do not neglect the complex representation thinking I am going to use my own simplified version.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for(ch=mystring; *ch; ch++)`?